# http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js is down please provide alternate link downloadable file

Tags: javascript, oauth

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js

Above link is down getting 404. Please provide alternate links or downloadable file. I am using OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce, OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign,OAuth.getParameterMap, OAuth.decodeForm methods in my code.

Answer (score 0):

bro. [Here you are](https://gist.github.com/romeoh/3302258)

p.s Also you need to use sha1 library for oauth.js, you can get it [here](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha1.js)